# Message Passing algorithm: misadjustement, study of convergence, for inexact MPA

Tags: pr.probability, signal-analysis

I am looking for resources (articles or other information) on the derivation of mis-adjustments and on the study of convergence for the message passing algorithm (MPA) and/or the inexact message passing algorithms over acyclic bipartite Tanner graph.

Any special resource would you recommend?

Thanks in advance.